# Where to store sharepoint paths in Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, global-variables

I am developing an Azure Function and have a question on where to store variables in the form of paths to sharepoint libaries.

I have several methods that should be able to access these variables, so I guess I am looking for a way to save these like some form of global variable, but is this best practice in OOP such as C#? And in that case, should I use `local.settings.json` for this or store them somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, settings.json is the way to go. When you deploy you can the override these settings in the *Configuration -> Application Settings* section in the Azure portal (or via Azure CLI).

Screenshots, CLI examples, and more can be found in the official *[Manage your function app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings)*. It states:

> When you develop a function app locally, you must maintain local copies of these values in the local.settings.json project file. To learn more, see [Local settings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the typical use case for [App Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings). They are available inside your Function as Environment variables.